H11DSi-NT compatible backplane with SATA interface
I have a Supermicro H11DSi-NT, with two SATA ports for 10 drives, and 12 bays BPN-SAS2-826EL1 with SMC2108 AOC-SAS2LP card.
I am going to use it with Proxmox ZFS file system. It is advised to not to use ZFS with a raid controller. So I want remove the RAID card.
Must I replace the backplane for SATA support?
This case board has support for 10 disks.
Or should I replace motherboard?
What do you advise?

It should suffice to delete the raid in the BIOS and use the disks separately.

Your card should support JBOD mode, configure it and make all disks JBOD; that will make them directly accessible to the OS without any RAID processing, just as HBA would. That's exactly what ZFS wants. See this answer for details; I am inclined to make this question duplicate of that one, because in hindsight, it's the same.

I think it does not support JBOD. But I will try those commands. Thank you.
